# How to change Tableview's custom cell width dynamically ?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a table view and its every cell`s width say 1024px , so my requirement is after clicking a cell tableview's width will change logically. And my table view is bit complex.
 Every cell contains a custom view which is defined in another class. Please help me..

Comment: Scenario 1:  why dont you reload the tableview and apply the check which view to assign for a specific cell on run time

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way to modify a single cell's width without changing the width of the table view, only height using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Therefore, you might want to change the width of the custom view inside your cell.

First, to get the cell in question, call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on your table view wherever you need (if you want to change the width on tap, that would probably be in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`).

To access your custom view, you may give your custom view a tag number inside of the UITableViewCell by setting the custom view's `tag` property when creating the cell or in the storyboard. Then, call `viewWithTag:` on the UITableViewCell instance to get the custom view, and modify the `width` of its `frame` property.

Another, perhaps more suitable option would be to use a custom `UITableViewCell` class for your table view cells. That would mean subclassing `UITableViewCell` and creating a property for your custom view, which would allow you to access the custom subview through the getter and then change its `frame` property.

If you need the width of the custom view's *container* to change (which is currently your cell), simply embed the custom view inside a `UIView` and modify the UIView's width rather than the `UITableViewCell`'s instance in the same manner described above.